# Batch Rename Files With Similar Name

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I am trying to create a batch script to rename downloaded files. After downloading, the files have similar names that include a timestamp. The timestamps in the name differ from the value of the "last modified" timestamp (typically by only a few seconds). For example:

```
Export_2013_11_06_15_13_31.csv
Export_2013_11_06_15_13_41.csv
Export_2013_11_06_15_13_51.csv
```

etc.

Each of these files needs to be renamed to a **SPECIFIC** name in alphabetical order according to their **last modified timestamp** (not the timestamp in the name). The most *recent* file must be named `Bart.csv`, the next `Carol.csv`, and the oldest `June.csv`.

Is there a way to ensure the files are renamed in the correct order?

Comment: If the actual file time stamps have these differences as well, check out the `dir /o` flag and options.  Something like `dir /a-d /b /o-d`

Comment: @DavidRuhmann How would I use that in the batch file? I'm not sure of what the line you posted is doing

Comment: To see the documentation for the `dir` command type [`dir /?`](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) on the command line.  The line I posted will list only files `/a-d` (no directories), remove formatting `/b`, and sort the files in descending date order `/o-d` (newest first).  This can then be combined with a `for /f` loop and the `ren` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off&setlocal
set "name1=Bart"
set "name2=Carol"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d') do (
    set "fname=%%~a"
    set /a counter+=1
    SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
    call set "nname=%%name!counter!%%"
    echo ren "!fname!" "!nname!%%~xa"
    endlocal
)
```

Remove `echo` to get it working.

Comment: Thanks so much @Endoro ! This does most of what I need. However it is renaming every file in the directory. How would I change it to only rename files which are named "*Export_*.csv" (ie. TodayExport2013_11_06_15_13_41.csv)

Comment: can you tell me why this is only working when the .bat file is in the directory where the files are located? I included the directory in the path "dir C:\Users\%username%\Downloads\Export_*.csv /b /a-d /o-d", however when I run it with the .bat file saved in a different directory it says it can't find the files.

Comment: the `dir` command does return a file path only with the `/s` parameter.