# Batch File Rename - Batch File needs to move from folder to folder

Tags: batch-file, renaming

New to batch file writing. We are unable to install a file renamer program at work so i am looking to find a way to create a batch file to do the job instead. I want to create a batch file that i can place in a folder and it will rename all files in that folder with a prefix, while deleting some text from the file name itself. I am happy to edit the prefix text (as it changes all the time) in Notepad each time but I need to be able to move the batch file to the different folders.

The files will be something like this RDS_117856.pdf

and they need to read as xxx-xxx-xxx-117856.pdf

Any help would be great.

I am using windows, only have access to Notepad and no other coding software so a .BAT file would be the easiest thing to create here.

Comment: There are tons of similar questions here and on the internet, you can try reusing the solutions, and in case of problems ask a specific question here. Currently there's no legit question in your post, it's just an offtopic announcement of your new endeavor.

Comment: Not to go way off topic here, but before I'd start looking into the process of creating a batch file to do everything you're looking for. First I'd check to make sure that your work terminal is capable of running a batch file. More often than not employers lock down stations to restrict running such files. as far as you're issue, look into `FOR`, `REN` and `MOVE`. Just append a `/?` for each available option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Rename Files With Similar Name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817912/batch-rename-files-with-similar-name)